# Craft and lat/long search

Tags: geo

I've used expression engine but not Craft. I am looking for a CMS more flexible than WordPress. I need to have admins enter location or addresses of meetings and then allow site users search for locations close to them or close to a specific address. Part of the use case is that meeting locations would be posted if the meeting is open or just a contact if the meeting is closed.

Would Craft be a good CMS for this? What about the geo stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Craft would be a great solution for that!

For the proximity search feature, check out the [Smart Map](https://www.doublesecretagency.com/plugins/smart-map) plugin. (Disclaimer: I'm the author.) It allows you to input addresses for each location, then your users can conduct a search to find the closest locations.

Comment: Smart Map is awesome!

Comment: Looks great! Follow up question...Is it possible to stick a pin in just the center of a zip code without a full address? Kind of a generalized location?

Comment: @EricSnyder best to ask that as a new question.  be sure and tag it with `plugin-smartmap`

Comment: Will do. Having a few other issues. When I get those straightened out it may solve this one. If not I'll start a new thread.